# how to write prioritized query ,like we r having 3 values in that we have to display the value which is having highest priority

Tags: sql

```
(CASE WHEN AVL.SHIFT_SOURCE ='Planned schedule'
                 THEN 'Planned schedule'
                 WHEN AVL.SHIFT_SOURCE <> 'Planned schedule'
                 THEN 'Assignment work schedule'
                 WHEN AVL.SHIFT_SOURCE <> 'Assignment work schedule'
                 THEN 'Normal working hours'
            ELSE NULL
            END)
```

this is condition
need to write it in prioritized manner.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "prioritized matter"? Also, your code wouldn't work as you expect. The second `WHEN` will evaluate to true if the `SHIFT_SOURCE` is not a `Planned Schedule`, meaning your third condition will never evaluate. 

If you want Planned Schedule to be the first to show, it's probably best to have a second table where you add a SHIFT_SOURCE column and a PRIORITY column. JOIN to that, and order by the PRIORITY. That way you can flexibly change orders at any time, and add additional shift_sources without having to re-do code.

Answer (score -1):

SQL `CASE` operation is already "prioritized" - it would return the first matching value from the list of `WHEN` options.

See here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp 
or here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql 
or find an alternative source for your database flavor :)